# Is there a faster way than looping over numpy arrays?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, loops, vectorization

If I have two numpy arrays of values; how can I quickly make a third array that gives me the number of times I have the same two values in the first two arrays?

For example:

```
x = np.round(np.random.random(2500),2)
xIndex = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

y = np.round(np.random.random(2500)*10,2)
yIndex = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)

z = np.zeros((100,1000))
```

Right now, I'm doing the following loop (which is prohibitively slow):

```
for m in x:
    for n in y:
        q = np.where(xIndex == m)[0][0]
        l = np.where(yIndex == n)[0][0]
        z[q][l] += 1
```

Then I can do a contour plot (or heat map, or whatever) of xIndex, yIndex, and z. But I know I'm not doing a "Pythonic" way of solving this, and there's just no way for me to run over the hundreds of millions of data points I have for this in anything approaching a reasonable timeframe.

How do I do this the right way? Thanks for reading!

Comment: You don't need the index at all. `n * 100` is the index

Comment: That's slick; I knew I was way overthinking that part of it. I'm reading your answer now and trying to figure out the np.add.at() function as I've not yet encountered it (still learning Python). Thanks!

Comment: It's basically doing `z[xi[:, None], yi] += 1`. Since the operation is unbuffered, multiple occurrences of the same index actually operate multiple times. The docs I linked explain with basically this exact use-case, but in 1D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can truncate the code dramatically.

First, since you have a linear scale at which you're binning, you can eliminate the explicit arrays `xIndex` and `yIndex` entirely. You can express the exact indices into `z` as

```
xi = np.round(np.random.random(2500) * 100).astype(int)
yi = np.round(np.random.random(2500) * 1000).astype(int)
```

Second, you don't need the loop. The issue with the normal `+` operator (a.k.a. [`np.add`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.add.html)) is that it's buffered. A consequence of that is that you won't get the right count for multiple occurrencs of the same index. Fortunately, ufuncs have an [`at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html) method to handle that, and `add` is a ufunc.

Third, and finally, broadcasting allows you to specify how to mesh the arrays for a fancy index:

```
np.add.at(z, (xi[:, None], yi), 1)
```

If you're building a 2D histogram, you don't need to round the raw data. You can round just the indices instead:

```
x = np.random.random(2500)
y = np.random.random(2500) * 10

z = np.zeros((100,1000))
np.add.at(z, (np.round(100 * x).astype(int), np.round(100 * y).astype(int)), 1)
```

Comment: How would I plot the 2d histogram with x, y, and z data? I don't see an option in matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d() to simply fill a bin, like in ROOT.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as it does exactly what the question asks; I might jump back on here if I can't get it working with the specifics of the task I'm working on now, but the original question is well answered here. Thanks again!

Comment: @HEPN008 You can use `plt.surf` or `plt.contour` to display 3D data

Comment: `np.add.at(z, (np.round(100 * x), np.round(100 * y)), 1)` seems to throw an error saying indices need to be integers; don't you suppose we'd have to change the dtype?

Comment: @amzon-ex. Thanks for the catch. Fixed. You definitely can't index with floats like you do in Matlab.

Comment: I had already put the "int()" operator around them in my code just as a precaution; good thing I did! This works a treat.

Comment: Since you all bring it up, is there a difference between np.round(100 * x).astype(int) and int(np.round(100 * x))? I used the latter, but I'd like to follow best practises (if there is any set protocol for this situation).

Comment: @HEPN008. The first is the only option for numpy arrays `int(...)` only works on strings and objects that have an `__int__` method, which arrays of more than one element do not. `astype` is a method of all numpy arrays.